# Google chart : Navigating to other page on click of the node link

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, organizational-chart

Hi I am using google [organisation charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart) for my web application in Codeigniter- PHP/Mysql. I have loaded the nodes of my chart from mysql database. And the text in the nodes are made as links. Everything is fine till now. But now I want to add href to the link, so that when user clicks on the link it should navigate to the details page, where the details of particular node is shown. I know, in order to show the details, there should be an Id of the node to fetch the data from database. 
So here's my question How can I add this id to the link?

Is there any way to do this? Can anyone please help me. Here is my code:

model:

```
public function getTreeMembersData()
{
    $this->db->select('E1.name AS memname,E2.name AS parentname,E3.name AS spouse');
    $this->db->from('tab_members AS E1');
    $this->db->join('tab_members AS E2', 'E2.member_id = E1.parent_id','left outer');
    $this->db->join('tab_members AS E3', 'E3.parent_id = E1.member_id AND E3.relation_id = 3','left outer');
    $this->db->where('E1.relation_id !=', 3);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function membertree()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) || isset($_SESSION['userid']))
    {
        $page['pagename'] = "membertree";
        $data['msg'] = $this->session->flashdata('msg');
        $this->load->view('header',$page);
        $data['treedata'] = $this->Family_model->getTreeMembersData();
        $this->load->view('membertree',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('Auth/login');
    }
}
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url="<?php echo base_url();?>";
  google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    var data;
    var chart;

  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Parent');

      data.addRows([<?php 
          foreach($treedata as $d)
          {  
              $memname = $d->memname;
              $parent = $d->parentname;
              $spouse = $d->spouse;
              ?>
          [{v:'<?php echo $memname;?>', f:'<a><?php echo $memname;?><a><div><a><?php echo $spouse;?></a></div>'},'<?php echo $parent; ?>'],
        <?php
          }
      ?>]);
      var options = {
                 'width':250,
                 'height':600};
    // Create the chart.
    var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
    chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);

function selectHandler() {
  var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
if(selectedItem) {
    var name = data.getValue(selectedItem.row,0);
    alert(name);
 }
}
  }
```

```
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-body">
            <div id="chart_div" class="chart"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: yes.. I can get the id.. But dont know how to use that id in that particular node..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are able to get the id from the query,
you can add in the address to the details page as a `'GET'` parameter in the `href` attribute.

something like...

```
<a href="http://address.to/details.php?id=<?php echo $id_field;?>"><?php echo $memname;?><a>
```

as in the data row...

```
[{v:'<?php echo $memname;?>', f:'<a href="http://address.to/details.php?id=<?php echo $id_field;?>"><?php echo $memname;?><a><div><a><?php echo $spouse;?></a></div>'},'<?php echo $parent; ?>'],
```

Comment: Yes..It helped.. You saved my day..!